# How to open a local file/url and include its output into another page via PHP

Tags: php, html, curl, include, file-get-contents

Hello I have a one page website (the entire site is in one page):

```
/index.html
```

I want to wrap the header and footer of that page around another page inside a folder on the server:

```
/folder/newpage.php
```

(with headers and footer of /index.html, but different content)

I've isolated the header and footer and saved them in separate files in the root:

```
/index_header.html
/index_footer.html
```

If launched from the root they display correctly but I can't seem to include them in the "newpage.php" because none of the CSS, JS and images inside the header and footer are loaded.

I've tried the following 4 methods:

```
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/index_header.html');

file_get_contents($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/index_header.html');

ob_start();
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/index_header.html');
$output = ob_get_clean();
echo $output;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/index_header.html");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
echo $output;
curl_close($ch);
```

But none of these methods work...
Can anyone help me out?
Thank you

Comment: Check [readfile()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile).

Comment: where are you linking to css, js and images? Is that code on the index.html page?

Comment: maybe this is too easy a fix but did you try renaming index.html to index.php? Most servers will not execute php code in an html file. Other than that I use `include 'my_file.hmtl` in my simple sites and it works fine.

Comment: @dalelandry correct... the index.html is a regular html file with CSS, JS and images

Comment: @MarkusZeller I tried that and it seems to behave the same as include()

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up changing all the JS, image and CSS calls to absolute urls starting from the root which allowed me to use include()
Thank you